# What mechanism(s) does Google Sign-in for use to share data between apps?

Tags: android, single-sign-on, google-signin

I am investigating methods for apps to share data between apps on Android platform, for example Chrome Custom Tabs. [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) seems to allow seamless SSO between any app.

Does anyone know what mechanism(s) Google Sign-in uses to share data between apps?

Is it special APIs only they have access to or those anyone can leverage to build their own SSO?

Comment: Have you seen Auth0?

Comment: Auth0 looks like it might be useful, but I am looking more to understand the platform at a lower level, since I may have a need to make a custom SSO solution.